# Deleting SPListItem in event receiver - very long time

Tags: event-receivers, splistitem, delete

I have an event reciever with ItemDeleting action, in which i try to delete an item from another list (I cant realy use cascade delet behavior here, I need to do some stuff that requires the receiver). The problem is, the code deleting the item executes for like 2 minutes, doesnt matter if I use SPListItem.Delete() or ProcessBatchData(). The receiver runs synchronously (thats actually a second problem - I can't change it to run async, which should be default...). The same code (item deleting) runs normally (fast) in a test, so I dont think there is anything wrong with it. Just posting Elements.xml of my receiver, hoping maybe this will help to see the issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListUrl="Lists/MyList">
      <Receiver>
        <Name>SomethingItemDeleting</Name>
        <Type>ItemDeleting</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>My.Class.SomethingReceiver.SomethingReceiver</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

Edit:
The code that executes so long is basically

```
_web.ProcessBatchData(batch);
```

Where batch is:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><ows:Batch OnError=\"Continue\"><Method><SetList Scope=\"Request\">e8bccd77-2a29-49f4-81b9-a7909babd3b6</SetList><SetVar Name=\"ID\">2487</SetVar><SetVar Name=\"Cmd\">Delete</SetVar></Method></ows:Batch>";
```

The same code outside the receiver executes in like 2 seconds. The same is when I run SPListItem.Delete(). The list from which the item is being deleted contains about 50 items (they are in 2-level folder hierarchy) and has no event receivers of its own

Comment: Please post the item deleting code as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue when my list have lookup fields with restriction on delete. ULS write that web is locked. Removing restrinction from lookup field fix this issue. I just don't know if this situations is as yours.

Comment: Ok, so on the list that caused the problems I had one more lookup, to some different list (X), where the 'cascade delete' behavior was selected. Removing it actualy helps, so thanks for the tip. I just dont know why this was causing a problem, if I understand correctly - when I delete an item form X, every item on my problematic list which has a lookup to that item will be deleted as well, but nothing like this occurs in my case